# Upper bound on the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}^d $. Assume the linear kernel $k(x,z)=x^Tz$ for $x,z \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $x_1 ,..., x_m \in \mathbb{R}^d$ as input patterns. I need to find an upper bound on the rank of the Gram matrix from the input patterns in terms of d and m.

I'm stuck on this exercise and really don't know how to proceed. My original idea was that the rank could not be greater than d but my problem is to include m in all of this.